# How to exclude job in Alertmanager?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a rule in Alertmanager:

```
  - alert: HostOutOfMemory
    expr: (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 < 10) * on(instance) group_left (nodename) node_uname_info{nodename=~".+"}
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: Host out of memory (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
      description: "Node memory is filling up (< 10% left)\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
```

Prometheus config:

```
  - job_name: "VM1"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["192.168.0.24:9100"]
  - job_name: "VM2"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ["192.168.0.25:9100"]
```

How to exclude job "VM1" for this rule?

Comment: Do you mean exclude targets scraped by some particular job from producing said alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All metrics have `job` label associated with them, based on job that scraped this metric.

To exclude metrics from a single job you can use `!=` selector:

```
node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job!="VM1"}
```

To exclude metrics from multiple jobs you can use `!=` selector multiple times, or use regex not matching selector `!~`:

```
node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job!="VM1", job!="VM2"}
```

or

```
node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job!~"VM[12]"}
```

Resulting expression from your question will look like this:

```
(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job!~"VM[12]"} / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 < 10) * on(instance) group_left (nodename) node_uname_info{nodename!=""}
```

Notice:

1. in your case it is enough to apply said filter to a single metric selector. Others will be filtered in the same way due to label matching of biary operations.
2. `nodename=~".+"` is semantically equal to `nodename!=""` - check that `nodename` is not empty. But latter with have better performance.

You can see demo of related queries [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=up%7Bjob!%3D%22random%22%2C%20job%20!%3D%22caddy%22%7D&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=up%7Bjob!%3D%22random%22%2C%20job%20!%3D%22caddy%22%7D%20%2B%20up&g2.tab=1&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h).

Answer (score 0):

Your metrics should have a "job" label with values "VM1" or "VM2" linked to it.
You can just add a filter in you alert expression such as :

```
node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job!="VM1}
```

It will exclude the metrics matching the label {job=VM1} from your alert.

Comment: Thank you! How can I exclude multiple VMs?
node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job!="VM1|VM2"}
It's right?

Comment: This would be done by using the regex selector : node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{job!~ "(VM1|VM2)"